# Azure function - connect to Azure SQL database using Active Directory Interactive authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm using SqlClient in my Azure function. Currently when I try to create a new instance passing the connection string, I receive the following message

```
Keyword not supported: 'authentication'
```

My connection string is

```
server=tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net;database=mydb;UID=AnyString;Authentication=Active Directory Interactive
```

My azure function has 'Identity' setting enabled.

My other .NET apps running as AppService are working excellent connecting to the same DB, but they use EntityFramework

I have tried to remove Authentication=Active Directory Interactive and also add the following line to the connection

```
 connection.AccessToken = new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

But I'm just getting different error messages like Login failed for user '' or Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Thanks!

Comment: By 'Identity' do you mean Managed Identity?

Comment: Yes, managed identity

Comment: Please check my answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success with the following steps:

#### 1. [Provision an Azure Active Directory administrator for your Azure SQL Database server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-azure-sql-database-server).

Note: Please ensure that you set a user as the AAD administrator for your Azure SQL Server.

#### 2. Connect to your Azure SQL Database with the AAD account in step 1. You can use SSMS or just connect to your database from the portal.

#### 3. Add service principal and assign a role

```
CREATE USER [Azure_AD_principal_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'Azure_AD_principal_name';
```

#### 4. Code sample

```
string sqlResource = "https://database.windows.net/";
string tenantId = "e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb";
string serverName = "{server}.database.windows.net";
string databaseName = "{database}";

var token = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync(sqlResource, tenantId).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

string sqlConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source=tcp:{0},1433;Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False", serverName, databaseName);


using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    connection.AccessToken = token;
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your case, `Azure_AD_principal_name` should be the managed identity name of your VM. Or, you may add your managed identity service principal to a security group, and use the group name as `Azure_AD_principal_name`, then all members in that group will be able to connect to your  Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient not System.Data.SqlClient namespace

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `connection.AccessToken` property is the only way of doing this in .NET Core as per this [conversation](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/10).

As for the error you are seeing with this, is probably because a user for the managed identity has not been created in the database. Follow the steps in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#grant-permissions-to-managed-identity) for that.

Here is the SQL Script for reference

```sql
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
GO
```

where `<identity-name>` is the name of the managed identity configured in Azure AD.